# Aoe_Scheduler Errors when trying to access the module on admin

Tags: magento-1, cron, crontab

Installed Aoe_Scheduler and now getting a http 500 error when trying to access the module on Admin.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your Apache or NGINX logs? Or any exceptions in Magento?

Comment: @MattAntley No no errors.